# 2 Templates to one SharePoint Library, Default templates

Tags: sharepoint

Ok, I'm not a script writer, otherwise I'd have this automated already. I need a quick assist in the most basic steps possible.

I have a SharePoint form library using InfoPath based forms. I have a "Public" template for my customers which submits to a "Private" library, through very granulated permissions so they cannot view the library. The Private library has it's own template based on the original Public template. This way I can transition one form's information seamlessly to the new template. The new Private template would have all of the internal details that we do not want the customer to see, but also all information fron the customer-filled Public form.

Is there any way to default all items opened from the Private library to use the Private Template, even though they were submitted form the Public template?

Answer (score 0):

Once an InfoPath form is submitted to a library it will always open in the template it was created in. In your case that is the Public template. There is a workaround for this scenario and it involves some programming. I would suggest that you create a custom logic in the form that would open a different view based on data entered. IE. once submitted you could change a value in your InfoPath form an make another view in the form default.

This is not ideal solution, but InfoPath does not support what you are looking for. InfoPath forms are pure XML and a super user might open the XML in some editor and see and update the values you are trying to protect.

The most aggressive option would be to change the reference to InfoPath template programatically, which is tricky as you might corrupt the form. However XML would still be there.